# не понимаю ошибку c#

Tags: c#, циклы

только учу c# и возникла проблема. Написал код заполнение двухмерного массива как в видео и все работало, вот код из видео:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("введите количество элементов по y ");

int y1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("введите количество элементов по x ");

int x1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

int[,] ddd = new int [y1, x1];

for (int y = 0; y < ddd.GetLength(0); y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < ddd.GetLength(1); x++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"введите значение индекса {x} массива под номером {y}");

        ddd[y, x] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
```

В коде видно, что для указание элементов массива, были созданы переменные в циклах `for (y,x)` но для большего понимания кода я решил указать переменные вне цикла, тот же самый код но только с объявлением переменных вне циклов:

```
Console.WriteLine("введите количество элементов по y ");

int y1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("введите количество элементов по x ");

int x1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

int[,] ddd = new int[y1, x1];
int y = 0;
int  x = 0;
for (; y < ddd.GetLength(0); y++)
{
    for (; x < ddd.GetLength(1); x++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"введите значение индекса {x} массива под номером {y}");

        ddd[y, x] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

но этот код уже не работал, я мог заполнить только один массив и при вводе некоторого количества элементов выдавало ошибки. Буду рад если объясните в чем дело

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Я, конечно, не знаток в C#, но мне кажется, что с этой строкой что-то не так: `for (; x < ddd.GetLength(1); x++)`.

Comment: Вместо удаления и создания копии вопроса, достаточно было отредактировать предыдущий вопрос. При большом количестве некачественных вопросов (включая удаленные) система может ограничить  пользователю возможность задавать новые вопросы

Comment: Во втором случае у вас `x` обнуляется только раз, а должен обнуляться после каждого завершения вложенного цикла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
for (int y = 0; y < ddd.GetLength(0); y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < ddd.GetLength(1); x++)
    {
```

В этом коде `x` обнуляется каждую итерацию цикла по `y`.

```cs
int y = 0;
int  x = 0;
for (; y < ddd.GetLength(0); y++)
{
    for (; x < ddd.GetLength(1); x++)
    {
```

А в этом коде `x` обнуляется только один раз - перед началом обоих циклов.

Конструкция циклов придумана именно такой как в первом варианте кода не зря, не нарушайте её, если не понимаете, зачем вы это делаете.

Answer (score 2):

В первом случае при каждой итерации внешнего цикла по Y, у вас заново запускался цикл по Х и переменной Х присваивалось значение 0.
Во втором случае, у вас запускается цикл по Х, но переменная Х уже имеет значение из предыдущей итерации цикла по Y.

Просто сбрасывайте значение Х в 0 после цикла по Х.